# Sorting Alphabetically Type Of Hashmap Values In Android

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, adapter

In my application i trying to sort Name by **Alphabetically** order in **listView** .Got successfully values from **Local Database** .May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective? I did't find any suitable solution.Please Help me out.

My code is below

```
// Declare this 
ArrayList < HashMap < String, Object >> Results;
ArrayList < HashMap < String, Object >> ValuesSpeciality;
public CustomAdapterSpecialityActivity adapterCustom;


//get speciality list from local db and show on listview
public void SpecialitiesOnList() {
    HashMap < String, Object > temp;
    List < TaxonomyObjects > contacts = db.getAllTaxonomy();

    for (TaxonomyObjects cn: contacts) {
        temp = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
        temp.put("provider", "" + cn.getDisplayName());
        temp.put("tvTaxonomyCode", "" + cn.getTaxonomyCode());
        System.out.println(temp);
        ValuesSpeciality.add(temp);
    }

    //searchResults=originalValuesSpeciality initially
    Results = new ArrayList < HashMap < String, Object >> (ValuesSpeciality);

    adapterCustom = new CustomAdapterSpecialityActivity(this, R.layout.list_item_service, searchResults);
    lv.setAdapter(adapterCustom);
    adapterCustom.notifyDataSetChanged();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapterCustom.getCount(); i++) {
        HashMap < String, Object > hm = (HashMap < String, Object > ) adapterCustom.getItem(i);

        hm.put("position", i);

    }
}
```

**As a result my Logcat shows this**

```
{Code=204D00000X, provider=Neuromusculoskeletal Medicine & OMM}  
 {Code=204F00000X, provider=Transplant Surgery}
 {Code=204R00000X, provider=Electrodiagnostic Medicine}
 {Code=207K00000X, provider=Allergy & Immunology}
 {Code=204E00000X, provider=Oral & Maxillofacial Surgery}
```

I trying to show **provider** Name `Alphabetically` order.

Comment: You don't sort a hash map.  A hash map is unsorted by its nature-  it uses a hash table, which is an unordered data type.  If you want to sort data, use a suitable data structure like a list or a tree.

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code
 ...

```
private static HashMap sortByValues(HashMap map) { 

       List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());

       // Defined Custom Comparator here
       Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {

            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

               return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
                  .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
            }
       });

       // Here I am copying the sorted list in HashMap
       // using LinkedHashMap to preserve the insertion order

     HashMap sortedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap();

       for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

              Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();

              sortedHashMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
       } 
       return sortedHashMap;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using local database then you can easily use `order by` on your TEXT field and this will given the result and use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap` and your problem will be solved easily